# how to serve files in a folder with a filename fetched from mysql database using php/.htaccess file?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, file-io

I have to serve files in a folder without a php script and with another filename that is fetched from DB.
example: this is the path to the file: "/app/123456.apk" but it should be provided with the name "example.apk". i mean when i enter "/app/123456.apk" it should be renamed to "/app/example.apk".

Comment: How do you expect the database to provide the `example.apk` name?

Comment: @RobW if it's possible direcly from .htaccess. if it's not from a php script for ex. /getname.php?id=12345

Comment: The logic here is flawed, either way the browser will have to visit the `getname.php` PHP file and then either (A) send the file with the proper name, or (B) redirect to the named file.

Comment: @RobW isn't it possible to serve a file with another name via .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, but you must know where to rewrite it to. You cannot query the database through `.htaccess`.

Comment: You can have static mod_rewrite rules all you want.. example: `RewriteRule ^app/my_cool_app\.apk$ /app/123456.apk [L]`

Comment: so that is impossible. the main problem is i can't serve files with php via multiple simultaneousls connections. is there anyway to solve it without x-send and byteserve function?

Comment: Why can't you.. there is no limit to how many PHP scripts are running.. the only limit is the number of server threads for the scripts to run in... You still need *something* to properly process the request!

Comment: this is the way i serve the files. but the problem persists.  
  
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header('Content-Type: '.$mime_types[$fileinfo['ext']]);
   header('Content-Length: ' . $fileinfo['size']);
   if (in_array_case_insensitive($fileinfo['ext'],$inBrowserExts)) {
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $fileinfo['name'].".".$fileinfo['ext']);
   }else{
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileinfo['name'].".".$fileinfo['ext']);
   };
   readfile($file);
   
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with an .htaccess rewrite rule that redirects urls of the form `app/*.apk` to a `getname.php` query with the appropriate id. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)\.apk$ /getname.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then in `getname.php` you can get the id with `$_GET['id']`, then look that id up in your database to find the filename on disk (`$diskname`) and the filename you want the user to save it as (`$savename`);

Given you have that information, you could write out the file with somethig like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($diskname)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $savename);
readfile($diskname);
```

Comment: how can i make that rule work with my current one? this is the rule i'm using. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Just put my `RewriteRule` on a line before the `RewriteCond`. That way any apk urls will have a chance to match before the more general index.php rule matches.